# Daniel Crenna il8n for Globalization

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, globalization

Has anybody used the above package for globalization of an MVC3 application?

[**danielcrenna i18n**](https://github.com/danielcrenna/i18n#readme)

I'm looking for a step-by-step guide if possible on how to do the above, especially with an existing MVC3 application.  And also, if there's any gotcha's to be aware of etc.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial [here](http://www.michaelwullink.com/2011/09/i18n-globalization-with-gettext-and-asp-net-mvc/) will help for sure. The project's [main page](https://github.com/danielcrenna/i18n) also contains some kinda step by step tutorial.